# Most convenient way to get a "2up" (2 pages per physical page / sheet) option for LPR?

Tags: linux, printing, duplex

I'm looking for something similar to [How to convert a 1 page PDF to a 2 page per sheet PDF?](https://superuser.com/questions/246092/how-to-convert-a-1-page-pdf-to-a-2-page-per-sheet-pdf), but that works like LPR instead of a PDF file converter. This institution has a custom version of `lpr` that has such an option [ [link](http://wiki.phys.ethz.ch/readme/how_to_use_lpr) ]; are there any more standard options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lpr` that comes with CUPS recognizes the [`number-up` option](http://www.cups.org/documentation.php/options.html#NUMBERUP). Just combine it with CUPS-PDF.