# Free PDF software that supports fancy imposition?

Tags: pdf, printing

Is there any (free) PDF printing software that supports page imposition?
I want to print this PDF 2-up, full-duplex on letter paper so that it can be cut in half and bound (or folded and stapled) into a book. That, of course, requires some nice tricks to get the proper front-back page matching.

Comment: It's possible to trick Foxit PDF Reader/Acrobat Reader into doing some basic imposition by printing 2-up, single-duplex odd pages, then flipping the paper, and then printing the even pages. But this would require test runs and I'd love to avoid all that trouble.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [bullzip](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php) supports this. You didn't say what OS you're using; bullzip is for Windows based machines.

Comment: Bullzip supports watermarks and superimposing on a background image, but not page imposition. I am on Windows and I have Bullzip freeware ver 7.1.1218.

Answer (score 0):

On linux there's a program called pdfshuffler, *"a small python-gtk application, which helps the user to merge or split pdf documents and rotate, crop and rearrange their pages using an interactive and intuitive graphical interface"*. Found by way of [How to convert a 1 page PDF to a 2 page per sheet PDF?](https://superuser.com/questions/246092/how-to-convert-a-1-page-pdf-to-a-2-page-per-sheet-pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use [this Dysprosium software](http://www.messiahpsychoanalyst.org/Documents/Downloads.html#part11) that creates "multi-up", that is 2-up, 3-up, matrix of m x n -up, in different configuration. It is free and cross platform.