# Reformat PDF to landscape, facing pages (2up them, magazine-style) while retaining links? (Windows)

Tags: windows, pdf, printing

I have a 1,000 page PDF with portrait pages. I want a 500-page PDF, with each page consisting of two original pages. Nothing exciting about the layout, just the same as what I'd get printing it "2 pages per sheet", e.g.:
[image of PDF program's print options set to 2 pages per sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGi2d.png)

The trick is that the PDF has internal links to pages and chapters, and I want those retained.

First approach was to use my PDF viewer software to print to a new file, but the links weren't retained. Then I went with software that merges pages (https://github.com/raffaem/pdfsak, which relies on Ghostscript and/or LaTeX), but again the links weren't retained.

Is this possible? I'm willing to consider purchasing something. I'm on Windows. Thanks!

Comment: Does this help : https://superuser.com/questions/246092/how-to-convert-a-1-page-pdf-to-a-2-page-per-sheet-pdf

Comment: Thanks, but no. It suggest PDFNup, but that drops the links like PDFSAK does. I didn't try PDFJAM because it says it hasn't been tested on Windows.